# Cheap device to take to school for light work

Tags: tablet

There are Easter Revision Sessions coming up and I can't write well so I am looking for something tablet/laptop that I will be able to write in. I also aim to use this for work for the next two years, as I need something inexpensive to take into school to write for Sixth Form.

- It needs to be cheap enough (under £100 but I can stretch just over *reluctantly*) so that I can take it in, I don't want to take something very expensive in case it gets lost/damaged.
- I also require it to be small and lightweight enough that I will be able to walk it to school every day and for it to fit in my bag.
- It needs to come with some form of a keyboard. If the device does not already have one then I will have to purchase one which will have to be compensated in the cost.
- It needs to have WiFi as I will be using Google Docs for the work. This means that it can have a low internal storage.
- It doesn't need to be that powerful, just enough that I am able to get my work done.
- A USB port as an optional extra, but this is not required.
- It needs a decent battery life because I will be using it for several hours, and a plug may not always be present all of the time.

It also needs to be purchasable in the UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

£100 is a pretty tight constraint, so I won't be able to pull into too many bells and whistles into this recommendation. What I managed to get as a baseline along these three tablets is **32 eMMC internal storage** and **2 gb of RAM**. I've recommended products you could purchase today that should be available to you in the UK. The only differences between these tablets is the CPUs:

- Option 1: Slowest
- Option 2: Slightly Better
- Option 3: Significantly Better

---

### Cheapest Option: Onda V80 SE Tablet £71.85 @ [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAAG56NT2967)

[image: Onda V80 SE Tablet]

This tablet features Android 5.1 and based on [it's review](http://www.androidcrush.com/onda-v80-se-tablet-review/) it features a older Intel Atom Z3735F Quad Core (Release: Apr, 2014). It's [benchmarks](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-x5-Z8350-vs-Intel-Atom-Z3735F) indicate this it will operate slower than any of the 3 options, meaning it will be the least "snappy" when used.

### Slightly Better Option: Onda V80 Plus £90.60 @ [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAD336HF8039)

[image: Onda V80 Plus]

This tablet features Android 5.1 + Windows 10 (I would recommend using the Android OS unless you need the additional features of Windows). It is functionally the same as the previous option, but with 2 OS's and a slightly better processor, 
Intel x5-Z8350 (Release: Jan, 2016) (it's Passmark score suggests it will perform about 26.5% better than the previous option). You might even want to consider uninstalling the Windows operating system for a little more space as it doesn't sound like the extra functionality is worth the performance hit.

### Budget Stretcher: Teclast P10 £98.99 @ [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAD336HF8103)

[image]

The most powerful of the Tablet options and using the newer Android 7.1 OS, this tablet will stretch your budget, however it is marginally more powerful ([according to benchmarks](https://www.androidbenchmark.net/phone.php?phone=Rockchip%20rk3368-box)). It's cpu (RK 3368-H) Passmark score suggest it will perform about 2.6x better than the Onda Plus option. This option will be the "snappiest" and unlike the previous Onda Plus option, won't come with the wasted space of Windows 10. Consider this option if you want the most bang for buck performance wise.

---

### Keyboard: Wanmingtek Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo £16.99 @ [Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAD8F6ME3049&cm_re=bluetooth_keyboard-_-9SIAD8F6ME3049-_-Product)

[image: Wanmingtek Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Combo £16.99 @]

None of the tablets I curated came with keyboards, most likely because of the low end price restriction. It's a cheap blue-tooth keyboard, weighs less than 300 grams and will get the job done. It also comes with a mouse if you don't feel like touching your screen. This will unfortunately put, option 2/3 slightly over budget.